# Wagtail 2.10 objects created programmatically don't show up in ParentalKey's InlinePanel, but exist in database and frontend

Tags: python, wagtail

Using Wagtail v2.10.

I have a `FuncionModel(Orderable)` with a parentalkey relationship to `EventoPage(Page)`:

```
parent = ParentalKey(EventoPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='funciones')
```

The **FuncionModel** instances are edited in the admin through an InlinePanel defined in **EventoPage**:

```
publicacion_panels = [
        InlinePanel('funciones', label='funciones')
    ]

edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
       ...
        ObjectList(funcion_panels, heading='Funciones'),
       ...
    ])
```

I'm also creating instances of **Funcionmodel** in **EventoPage's** save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.delete_functions:
        self.funciones.all().delete()
    if self.generate_functions:
        daterange = pd.date_range(self.startdate, self.enddate)
        times = []
        if self.time_1:
            times.append(self.time_1)

        if self.time_2:
            times.append(self.time_2)

        if self.time_3:
            times.append(self.time_3)

        for date in daterange:
            if date.weekday() in self.get_weekdays():
                for time in times:
                    funcion, created = FuncionModel.objects.get_or_create(parent=self, date=date, time=time)
                    funcion.save()
        self.generate_functions = False
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What happens is that the **FuncionModel** instances created in the save method show up in the database and the frontend, but they don't appear in the InlinePanel. E.g. I have a **FuncionModel** already created through the inline panel, and create 2 more in the save method, all 3 show up in the frontend but only the one created in the InlinePanel appears in the admin site.

---

SOLVED, using gasman's suggestion:
I added `self.save_revision()` after creating the `FuncionModel` instances, and called the whole thing from a `post_save` signal.

Working code:

```
 def process_functions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.delete_functions:
            self.funciones.all().delete()
        if self.generate_functions:
            daterange = pd.date_range(self.startdate, self.enddate)
            times = []
            if self.time_1:
                times.append(self.time_1)

            if self.time_2:
                times.append(self.time_2)

            if self.time_3:
                times.append(self.time_3)

            for date in daterange:
                if date.weekday() in self.get_weekdays():
                    for time in times:
                        if not FuncionModel.objects.filter(parent=self, date=date, time=time):
                            funcion = FuncionModel(parent=self, date=date, time=time)
                            funcion.save()
                            self.save_revision()
            self.generate_functions = False
            self.save()




@receiver(post_save)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if issubclass(sender, EventoPage):
        kwargs['instance'].process_functions()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the page's `funciones` relation, you should call the page's `save_revision()` method.

In order to support saving pages as draft (where you wouldn't want the draft version of the page to overwrite the live version as stored in the database), page revisions are stored in a separate `PageRevision` model - the page edit view retrieves the latest version of the page from that table, rather than the EventoPage table.